# Theme Preprocess Conditional Field Display

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, display-suite

Looking for a way to preprocess two fields. I am trying to hide Field 1 from display if Field 2 has value.

If Field 1 has value and Field 2 has value display Field 2 only. 
If Field 1 has value and Field 2 has NO value display Field 1.

This should only apply to content type USER POSTS. And I am using Display Suite to arrange the fields if that makes a difference.

What would be the preprocess hook to place on mytheme.theme?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you hide it with CSS? In which case you could do something simple like:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_hook().
 *
 * Adapt logic, field names etc to suit your needs.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (empty($variables['node']->get('my_field_2')->value)) {
    $variables['page_classes']['#plain_text'] .= ' field_two--display-none';
  } 

}

/* CSS */
.field_two--display-none { display: none; }
```

Not super elegant but would do the trick.

Your other option is to use the [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

Comment: Can you help me understand the if statement? Does it say if my_field_2 is empty then set this CSS class or if my_field_2 has value then set this CSS class?

Comment: It's asking: Does `$variables['node']->get('my_field_2')->value` return an empty value? If so, then apply the CSS class to hide this field. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: This needs a little bit of tweak and I am stuck. The logic  I am trying to implement is: If field_2 retruns value (is not null), apply hide css to field_1. Example: Field 2 is the video, if video exist hide field 1 which is the image. Any tips?